# Решение задачи: 3 последовательных значения

Tags: python, python-3.x, коллекции, for

Методом последовательного подбора чисел из списка (x) нужно найти 3 последовательных значения которые равны списку (у). Как можно решить эту задачу? Вот мой код, как я пытался сделать

```py
x = [12, 111,999, 333333, 22222222, 408, 1142, 326, 734, 45, 281,] 
y = [734, 45, 281]
    
#подбор первого числа которая больше 500 но меньше 1500
for i in range(len(x)):
    if 500 <= x[i] <= 1500 : break
z = x[i:i+3] 
if y == z:
    print("верно")
else:
    print("не верно")
```

Comment: Откуда в коде взялась проверка `500 <= x[i] <= 1500`? Про это ничего нет в задаче. Вы взяли просто первый попавшийся код и даже не попробовали его приспособить под свою задачу? Так то у вас есть весь нужный код дальше, вам нужно просто правильно всё это скомпоновать в цикле и вообще.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Эту задачку можно решить в лоб через срезы:

- Перебираем индексы `x`
- Берем у `x` срез от текущего индекса и на длину `y`
- Если срез равен `y`, то завершаем перебор и выводим что `верно`

Наглядно на итерациях:

- `i = 0`, `sub_arr = [12, 111, 999]`
- `i = 1`, `sub_arr = [111, 999, 333333]`
- ...
- `i = 8`, `sub_arr = [734, 45, 281]`

Пример:

```
x = [12, 111, 999, 333333, 22222222, 408, 1142, 326, 734, 45, 281, ]
y = [734, 45, 281]

found = False
for i in range(len(x)):
    sub_arr = x[i:i+len(y)]
    if sub_arr == y:
        found = True
        break

print("верно" if found else "не верно")
```